# Using android DataBinding library how to pass parameters to binding events

Tags: android-databinding

I followed examples from Android Developers [Binding Events](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) and implementing step-by-step. That working fine. But I want to send parameters from adapter to handlers, how can achieve this using data binding handlers

Comment: What have you tried so far? please post your code. and what kind of parameter you are trying to pass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the answer.
In xml for onclick use lambda expression

```
layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="movie"
        type="embitel.com.databindingexample.helper.Movie" />

    <variable
        name="handler"
        type="embitel.com.databindingexample.helper.MyHandlers" />

</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
```

> ```
>     android:onClick="@{(view)->handler.onItemClicked(view,movie)}"
> ```

```
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:error="@{@drawable/ic_launcher}"
            app:imageUrl="@{movie.imageUrl}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{movie.title}" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

then create handler class as,

```
public class MyHandlers {

public void onItemClicked(View v, Movie movie) {
    Context context = v.getContext();
    context.startActivity(DetailActivity.buildIntent(context, movie));
}
```

}

then you need to set handler where that xml is iflated as,

```
binding.setHandler(new MyHandlers());
```

you can also put handler method in any class. In that case you have to set that class name as handler.

Comment: How can I do this without using lambdas?